# MySQL: Move data from one table to another with different schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with a bad design:

```
CREATE TABLE token (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    token VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    expiration TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The reason I see it as bad now even though it worked well before is because now I cannot reuse that `token` table if I want a token related to an email or something else. I could just add `email_id` column but then I would need ugly logic to determine if the token is meant for a user or an email, respectively.

I want to normalize this design such that I can have a single `token` table that isn't coupled to any `user_id` or `email_id`, and have `user_token` and `email_token` pivot tables for the relations.

But I am also using migrations so I can't just rewrite my schema. I need to modify this on the fly with data present in the database.

I need to do the following:

1. Create new `user_token` and `email_token` tables **(COMPLETE)**
2. Copy `token.id` to `user_token.token_id` column, and copy `token.user_id` value to `user_token.user_id` column. The copying needs to be done in an `INSERT` statement since the `user_token` table will be brand new with no data **(TODO)**
3. Remove `token.user_id` column **(COMPLETE)**

Step 2 is the part I need help on. Any help would be appreciated to write that query.

This is what the new schema will look like if it helps to create a query for step 2:

```
CREATE TABLE token (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    token VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    expiration TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_token (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    token_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (token_id) REFERENCES token (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE email_token (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    token_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (email_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (token_id) REFERENCES token (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you haven't delete token.user_id and token.email_id columns from token table, then you can copy them by using a simple INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO user_token (user_id, token_id)
SELECT user_id, id
FROM token

INSERT INTO email_token (email_id, token_id)
SELECT email_id, id
FROM token
```

if you want to copy created_at, updated_at, and deleted_at columns along with them, you could just add them into the query:

```
INSERT INTO user_token (user_id, token_id, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at)
SELECT user_id, id, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
FROM token

INSERT INTO email_token (email_id, token_id, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at)
SELECT email_id, id, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
FROM token
```

this will copy them into the new tables. Then, you only need to delete user_id and email_id columns from token table by a simple ALTER :

FIRST DELETE FOREIGN KEY:

```
ALTER TABLE token DROP FOREIGN KEY user_id
```

THEN DELETE THE COLUMNS:

```
ALTER TABLE token DROP COLUMN user_id;
ALTER TABLE token DROP COLUMN email_id;
```

Comment: Bravo :) never had to do something like this before, thanks for the tips.